# Не понятно, как работать с циклом в Python

Tags: python, list, циклы, while, index

Помогите пожалуйста с простейшей задачей ♥ 
Дан список q, например, `q = [0, 196, 2, 6, 25, 2]` 
Нужно создать список Q, в котором все элементы, начиная с `Q[2]`, определяются по формуле: 
`Q[i] = q[i]*Q[i-1]+Q[i-2]`
а первые два элемента `Q[0] = 1, Q[1] = 0`. 
Заполнять список Q нужно до тех пор, пока его крайний элемент не станет равен некому f. 
Казалось бы, все просто, но ни черта не работает. Я попробовала написать так:

```py
f = 131040
q = [0, 196, 2, 6, 25, 2]
Q = [1,0]
while Q[i] != f:
  for i in range (2,100000):
    Q[i] = q[i]*Q[i-1]+Q[i-2]
```

Пишет list assignment index out of range и еще много очевидных вещей. Я не знаю, как реализовать это иначе, хелп
P.S. я не являюсь программистом

Comment: что означает  q[i]  для i равного, например, 10 ?

Comment: А где гарантия того, что в какой-то момент крайний элемент станет равен f? В списке q не бесконечное количество элементов, даже правильно работающая программа при таких данных не дает f

Comment: @ClickName судя по f и диапазону цикла, это ожидается явно не на первых 6 элементах :)

Comment: Q.append(q[i]*Q[i-1]+Q[i-2])   А так я согласен с предыдущими высказываниями. Кто сказал, что получится число f ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого

```
f = 131040
q = [0, 196, 2, 6, 25, 2]
Q = [1,0]

for i in range (0,len(q)):
    Q.append(q[i]*Q[i+2-1] + Q[i+2-2])
    if Q[i+2] == f:
        print("Found!!!")
        break
print(Q)
```

Found!!!

[1, 0, 1, 196, 393, 2554, 64243, 131040]

Comment: у вас неправильная формула

Comment: Правильная- индескы начинаются с 0, а для Q с 2. Работает как надо. А дополнительные числа в индексах, чтобы понятно было:)

Comment: Прежде чем минусовать, разобраться надо:)

Comment: ну вот и разберитесь чему должен быть равен элемент Q[2] в задании и чему он будет равен у вас. То, что работает "как надо" это вам кто сказал?

Comment: Q[2] = q[0] * Q[1] + Q[0] = 0*0+1 = 1

Comment: а теперь давайте сравним вашу формулу с формулой в задании: Q[2] = q[**2**] * Q[1] + Q[0]

Comment: Вы не учитываете, что это учебное задание. Иначе откуда взялось число f == 131040 при данном наборе значений q?
Список q нужно представить как [0,0, 0, 196, 2, 6, 25, 2] для выравнивания индексов.

Comment: [1, 0, 1, 196, 393, 2554, 64243, 131040] - совпадает с эталонным результатом, если находить значения вручную. СПасибо солнышко, вы мне очень помогли! Успехов вам :)

Comment: Пометьте ответ как решение и закройте вопрос:)